# MVC Access Controller through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to access the controller through js and display the result in modal window. I need to use get method in JS to access it, but it doesn't fire on click.
What might be the problem here?

Yeah, my bad with the parentheses. Still doesn't do anything.

EDITED CODE:

```
$('#delete_btn').on('click', function () {
        $.get("/List/Delete", { param: 17 }, function (data) {
            $('#modal_window').replaceWith('<div id="modal_window">' + data + '</div>');
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Extra right parenthesis after `'click'` - needs to be `$('#add_btn').on('click', function (event) {` and then finish with `});`

Comment: There is an extra right parenthesis after `$('#add_btn').on('click')` Must be `$('#add_btn').on('click', function...`

Comment: @ChandrasekarG I've corrected it, still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Does the click handler even get executed? Or is it the ajax call that doesn't work? You can check by pressing F12 to get the developer console, then setting a breakpoint on the first line of the event handler.... Since we can't see your page we would just be guessing... is the ID of the button definitely delete_btn?